# Cannot access variable in Plotly when hovering

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I prepared a map for a presentation with `ggplot()`. From this map, I want to transform it into a plotly object so I can see additional information when hovering over it.

```
library (ggplot2)
library (plotly)

long <- c(-39.98346, -39.99708, -39.97745, -39.90892,-39.73878, -39.73567, -39.76973, -39.95023)
lat <- c(-3.161511, -3.198613, -3.232549, -3.274145, -3.356805, -3.397217, -3.458218,-3.433217)
order <- c(11, 12, 13, 14, 11, 12, 13, 14)
hole <- c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
piece <- c("1", "1", "1", "1" ,"1" ,"1", "1", "1")
group <- c("20.1" , "20.1" , "20.1" , "20.1" , "203.1", "203.1" ,"203.1", "203.1")
id <- c(20 , 20, 20  ,20 ,203 ,203 ,203, 203)
qty <- c(64.3 ,64.3 ,64.3 ,64.3,38.8, 38.8,38.8 ,38.8)
city <- c("city_A", "city_A", "city_A", "city_A", "city_B", "city_B", "city_B", "city_B" )
map <- data.frame (long,lat,order=as.integer(order),hole,piece,group, id,qty,city,stringsAsFactors = F)

gg_map <- ggplot(data = map)+
geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = qty))
gg_map # successfully create the map

plotly_map <- ggplotly(gg_map, tooltip = c("qty", "city")) #conversion of a ggplot map to a plotly map
plotly_map # I cannot visualize city information when hovering
```

I expected that when hovering over `plotly_map` I would be able to visualize both `qty` and `city`, but it only shows `qty`. It seems that plotly misses connection with data frame data when converting.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

As it says in `?ggplotly`, the `tooltip` argument is

> a character vector specifying which **aesthetic mappings** to show in the tooltip.

So, the issue is that `city` is not an aesthetic in `gg_map`. Here's a solution that uses `city` as a useless aesthetic:

```
gg_map <- ggplot(data = map)+
  geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = qty, noReason = city))
plotly_map <- ggplotly(gg_map, tooltip = c("qty", "city"))
plotly_map
```

[image]

Comment: I did not know one may create an unknown aesthetics. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @FabioCorrea, no problem. I don't know any other uses of doing that either. Note, though, that in this case you could have also used `group = city` with the same result.